# Counting possible coordinate moves with recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write a method that does the following:

```
public class GridCounting {
    /** Returns the total number of possible routes (paths) from
     * (x,y) to (tx,ty).
     * There are only three valid kinds of moves:
     *  Increment x by one.
     *  Increment x by two.
     *  Increment y by one.
     *
     *  Hint: You'll need to two base cases.
     */
    public static int count(int x,int y, int tx, int ty) {
        if (x==tx && y==ty)
            return 1;
        if (x>tx || y>ty)
            return 0;
        if (x<tx)
            return 1 + count(x+1, y, tx, ty);
        if (x<tx) //if x is still less, then we can do another move
            return 1 + count(x+2, y, tx, ty);
        if (y<ty){
            return 1 + count(x, y+1, tx, ty);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The trouble that I'm having is that I'm always off by +1. It expects 4 but I give it 5. The confusing part is that if I feed the function count(10,15,10,15), then that still counts as 1 move. I dont know how to account for this.

Also y++ then x++ counts as 1 move, and x++ then y++ counts as another move.
Edit: Fixed code:

```
public static int count(int x,int y, int tx, int ty) {
    if (x==tx && y==ty)
        return 1;
    if (x>tx || y>ty)
        return 0;
    if (x<tx)
        return count(x+1, y, tx, ty) + count(x+2, y, tx, ty) + count(x,y+1,tx,ty);
    if (y<ty) {
        return count(x, y+1, tx, ty); // what does this do?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *so I guess I have to count that as 1 move*  That's not one move, that's one path of zero length (having no moves, like empty set has no elements)

Comment: This function will have terrible performance for even moderately small values (like a 0,0,12,12 path). A lookup table should be used to store computed values, so that they don't have to be repeatedly calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The trouble that I'm having is that I'm always off by +1. It expects 4 but I give it 5.*
In position `(x, y)` we, generally speaking, have three choices (`x+=1`, `x+=2`, `y+=1`). Each of them produces separate paths and we need to find how many paths there're in total.
So, this part is wrong

```
        if (x<tx)
            return 1+ count(x+1, y, tx, ty);
        if (x<tx)
            return 1+ count(x+2, y, tx, ty);
        if (y<ty){
            return 1+ count(x, y+1, tx, ty);
        }
        return 0;
```

That was a hint, let me know if you need more.

*Also y++ then x++ counts as 1 move, and x++ then y++ counts as another move.*
Well, that sounds like two different paths to me.

**edit**
Ok, `return count(x + 1, y, tx, ty) + count(x + 2, y, tx, ty) + count(x, y + 1, tx, ty);` is all you need.
If there're 3 paths starting with first move `x + 1`, 2 paths starting with first move `x + 2` and 2 paths starting with first move `y + 1`, then, obviously, there're `3 + 2 + 2` paths total.

Comment: Im having a hard time thinking of how to account for two different moves that x can make..what can I do about that?

Comment: @fprime Are you saying that increasing x by two and increasing x by 1 twice should produce same route? I was under impression that's different routes.

Comment: You know Im not really sure..see edit I posted the test cases.

Comment: Yes I think youre right: x+2 x+1 is one path, x+1(3) is another route, and x++ x+2 is another path

Comment: You know what I think I was counting 'moves' in my code rather than paths..but I have no idea how I would count paths

Comment: @fprime Yes, from your test cases it looks like those are different paths. So, you need just to construct `count(x, y, tx, ty)` from `count(x + 1, y, tx, ty)`, `count(x + 2, y, tx, ty)` and `count(x, y + 1, tx, ty)`.

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @fprime Another hint: try adding them up. If there're 3 paths starting with first move `x+1`, 2 paths starting with first move `x+2` and 2 paths starting with first move `y+1`, then, obviously, there're 3+2+2 paths total.

Comment: I dont get it:( How would I implement this

Comment: @fprime: Keep a running total.  Instead of returning 1 + the recursive count, add the count to the total for each case.  (Don't add 1 to that count; the recursion will take care of that.)  Return the total at the end.

Comment: @Nikita OK I've been trying to analyze what you told me. See edits. The part about adding em all makes sense, but I dont understand the second part, `if (y<ty)` When does that run? Doesnt the previous step take care of this step? I'm trying to imagine how it runs but I cant. If I run count(on something) and passes the condition if (x<tx), it returns something. Does it then continue to the next condition, or thats it-that call is done?

Comment: @fprime You don't need `if (y<ty)` in this case. If `y` gets too large, your function will return `0` and nothing is added up to the sum. Or you can follow advice by **cHao** and do three separate statements, each one like `if (y<ty) { result += count(x, y+1, tx, ty); }`.

Comment: But if I remove if (y<ty), I fail the test cases.

Comment: @fprime which one? You still have `if (x>tx || y>ty) return 0;`.

Comment: Oh wait nm I made it an else statement for the x and removed y and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You sure this line is right?

```
if (x==tx && y==ty)
  return 1;
```

It seems like it should return zero.

On a phone so I can't test it.

Comment: Well ya the weird part is there is a test case that says `assertEquals(1,GridCounting.count(10,15,10,15));` so I guess I have to count that as 1 move

Comment: On a phone - that's some hard core stack overflowing. :)

Answer (score 0):

`if (x==tx && y==ty) return 1;` doesn't sound correct.  If you're already at the destination, there are no more routes.

Comment: Well ya the weird part is there is a test case that says assertEquals(1,GridCounting.count(10,15,10,15)); so I guess I have to count that as 1 move

Comment: @fprime: Well that test case doesn't make any sense!  Do you have a test case for e.g. `(10, 15, 11, 15)`, i.e. one cell away?

Comment: there's exactly one path from point (10, 15) to point (10, 15): path of length zero. That's how I see it.

Comment: From a square to the one "next door", the only possible path is a single step, incrementing the appropriate coordinate by 1.  Iff a path can consist of 0 steps, a path from a square to itself would be an empty path, and the only possible path.  Hence how both counts can be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I not understanding the rules, but I think it's that first base case that's causing your problem.  If you're already at the location then you're not making a move.

Comment: You're misunderstanding.  The count is of paths, not moves.